# How could Mitsuki attain Sage Mode without training?

Tags: boruto

During the final test, Mitsuki was subconciously able to enter into Sage Mode without prior training at any of the Great Sage Lands.
[image]
How was this possible?

Comment: Orochimaru's experiment? Like, he somehow injected sage power to Mitsuki, and Mitsuki just unconsciously activated it?

Comment: the sage mode mitsuki entered is on a completely different level when compared to any other sage mode we've seen in Naruto (Even Kabutos) @Albert His sage mode seems more like a snakish Chakra mode than anything else and i don't think Orochimaru would have wanted to inject sage mode into his son? We all know that those who aren't compatible usually always die

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin mitsuki was made to be a perfect being, thats another possibility. he had all memories of failure wiped and was created by the best in that specialty/area